# powershell determine os architecture

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with this code. It prints "x86 operating system", even though the write-host, `$OSArchitecture`, states the architecture is 64-bit.

```
$OSArchitecture = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object    OSArchitecture -ErrorAction Stop).OSArchitecture
write-host = $OSArchitecture

if ($OSArchitecture -eq '*64*') 
{
    Write-Host "x64 operating system" 
    $Version = Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\wow6432node\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | Where-Object {
    $_.DisplayName -Eq 'Microsoft Lync 2013'} | Select-Object DisplayVersion
} 
else 
{
    Write-Host "x86 operating system"
    $Version = Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | Where-Object {
    $_.DisplayName -Eq 'Microsoft Lync 2013'} | Select-Object DisplayVersion 
}
```

Update:
I get this error: `Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32"`.

Comment: You can't use wildcards with the `-eq` operator. You could use `-like '*64*'` or `-match '64'`.

Comment: If you are going to use wildcards (*), then the operator should be `-Like` instead of `-eq`.

Comment: i still get the : Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32". At line:6 char:21

Comment: If i remove Wow6432Node, it actually works.. any ideas?

Comment: @Bendo1984 Could you add the complete error in your question please?

Comment: What is on line:6 char:21? The code you put up there is not likely to cause that conversion error.

Comment: Just opened a new session, it works now - thx

Answer (score 4):

On x64 system `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem` gives `$true`. Therefore, you could do this:

```
if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) 
{
    Write-Host "x64 operating system" 
    $Version = Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\wow6432node\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | Where-Object {
    $_.DisplayName -Eq 'Microsoft Lync 2013'} | Select-Object DisplayVersion
} 
else 
{
    Write-Host "x86 operating system"
    $Version = Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | Where-Object {
    $_.DisplayName -Eq 'Microsoft Lync 2013'} | Select-Object DisplayVersion 
}
```

Comment: How would you use this in my script?

Comment: @Bendo1984 I updated Novakov's answer to show usage. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code.

```
$OSArchitecture=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OSArchitecture
if ($OSArchitecture -eq "64-bit") {
  Write-Output "x64 operating system" 
  $Path="HKLM:\software\wow6432node\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall"
} 
else {
  Write-Output "x86 operating system"
  $Path="HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall"
}

$Version=Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\software\wow6432node\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall" | ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath } | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq 'Microsoft Lync 2013'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayVersion
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this for this job

```
if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) { "32-bit" } else { "64-bit" }
```

or change in your code

```
if ($OSArchitecture -match '64')
```

Comment: i still get the : Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32". At line:6 char:21

Comment: If i remove Wow6432Node, it actually works.. any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't indicates whether OS is x64 or x86. It shows only process bitness. Type it in PowerShell x86.